# Writing to file in a directory in Android (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, save, output

I have a json string I would like to write to a file in the internal storage, as it will serve as the app's savefile. Since there will be several of them, I want all the files to be inside a directory called savefiles, that should be also created, if not found. I tried to achieve this using OutputStreamWriter, first I generate the file's path and then try to write to it. Here's the code:

```
        try {
            val path = "savefiles/${SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(Date())}.json"
            val outputStreamWriter = OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(path, Context.MODE_PRIVATE))
            outputStreamWriter.write(myJson.toString())
            outputStreamWriter.close()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: $e")
        }
```

However, this gives me the error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /savefiles/20230708174147.json contains a path separator`

I have come to understand that I shouldn't include the name of the directory in the path string, but haven't been able to find a way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a directory and write a file inside it in the internal storage of an Android device using **Kotlin**, you can follow these steps:

Here's the complete code snippet that incorporates the above steps:

```
val directory = File(context.filesDir, "savefiles")
if (!directory.exists()) {
    directory.mkdirs()
}

val fileName = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date()) + ".json"
val file = File(directory, fileName)

try {
    val outputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
    outputStream.write(myJson.toString().toByteArray())
    outputStream.close()
} catch (e: IOException) {
    Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: $e")
}
```

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for, works perfectly. Thank you

Comment: if (!directory.exists()) {
   if (! directory.mkdirs()) return;
} Check the return value as mkdirs might fail.

Comment: Md. Kabir Hassan - Welcome back to Stack Overflow. It looks like it's been a while since you've posted and may not be aware of the current policies since most or all seven of your recent answers appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. We do hope you'll stick around and continue to be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.